# How to set a custom View in ActionBar's navigation tabs and make the tabs adapt to its height?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the `ActionBar` and I want to set a custom `View` in the navigation tabs.

The height of the tabs seem to be fixed, and my custom `View` is larger, so it does not fit.

I try to customize the style as shown below, but it does not make the tabs higher...

How can I have the height of the tabs adapt to my custom `View` size?

(I know I could use `Tab`'s `setIcon` and `setTitle` in my case, but I still want to use a custom `View`)

[image]

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>   
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
    </style>

     <style name="MyTabStyle" parent="@android:Widget.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:height">85dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.

            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.about);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText("About");


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setCustomView(view)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    /*****/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this keep the actionbar on the top, but i don't know why !

```
ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
```

the actionbar stay in the top :

```
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM  | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

the tabs go on the top of the actionbar :

```
actionbar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't change the height of the action bar tabs. But you can achieve the intended behaviour by using a TabHost along with a ViewPager. 
This way you can add custom views to your TabIndicators and also have the swiping functionality.