# How to do Up navigation using ActionBar's tabs and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the `ActionBar` and tab navigation with `Fragments`.

Each tab contain a `Fragment` FragmentX with a `ListView`, and when clicking on an item of a list FragmentX is replaced by another `Fragment` FragmentY with the detail of the item.

How can I set the Up button of the `ActionBar` to load FragmentX when I'm in FragmentY?

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) shows that the navigation should be done between `Activities`, but the `ActionBar`'s navigation tabs allow to navigate between `Fragments`, not `Activities`.

What am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
     * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
     * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager
        .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.

            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab, null);

            ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageResource(tabIconList[i]);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(tabTitleList[i]);


            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    .setCustomView(view)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.


            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch(position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new MyListFragment1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MyListFragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new MyListFragment3();
                break;
            default: fragment = new MyListFragment1();

            }

            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use the `ActionBar` in the end. Too many constraints (I had [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128836/how-to-set-a-custom-view-in-actionbars-navigation-tabs-and-make-the-tabs-adapt) and I wanted to add a `View` above the `ActionBar`, which seemed complicated).

It was much simpler doing my own layout from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Active up navigation when you load FragmentY.
Then intercept up navigation on **onOptionsItemSelected**, just popup the backstack and launch your FragmentX.

I've done a rapid search on SO and i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086840/actionbar-up-navigation-with-fragments), wich inspired me.