# Custom Tab Bar with images

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to create a tab-bar like the one shown in the image below ( i.e. a tab-bar with some images on the left ) .

[image]

The white part are two images while the black part are the tab-labels

Can anyone guide me in doing the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a workaround without using action bar . Just some XML code tweaking , and I was good to go . Here's what I did :

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_bg" >

       <LinearLayout 
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/options"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/img"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear">
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  `actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                    //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                    .setCustomView(view)
                    .setTabListener(this));`
Here, you customize your layout and parse it into view
See [[How to set a custom View in ActionBar's navigation tabs and make the tabs adapt to its height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128836/how-to-set-a-custom-view-in-actionbars-navigation-tabs-and-make-the-tabs-adapt])

Comment: Using action bar is necessary to make such a tab-bar ? Isn't there any other way ? Sorry if the question is noobish , but I'm new to android .

Comment: Tab-bar? Hmmm, you can use tab-host :)
Of course, you can simply add a layout at the top and customize it.